# Boxplot for the 2 variables

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df. I need a box plot for 2 variables(Cat1 and Cat2) side by side. I know this can be by transposing the dataframe. But is there a way to do this without transposing. Is there a way to do this box plot in ggplot?

```
df
                   da Cat1  Cat2 Cat3
1 2016-06-04 04:05:45   25   58   45
2 2016-06-04 04:05:46   56   65   56
3 2016-06-04 04:05:45   45   54   47
4 2016-06-04 04:05:46   78   56   89
```

Some thing like below I am expecting[image]

Answer (score 0):

The basic step is to turn your data into a so-called 'tidy' data set ([see here](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html)).

The package `tidyr` has a function `gather` for just this purpose:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df = data.frame(
  Cat1 = rnorm(50),
  Cat2 = rnorm(50),
  Cat3 = rnorm(50)
)

# 'long' version of df
dL = gather(df,key = 'category',value = 'y')

ggplot(data = dL) +
  geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(x = category,y = y))
```

Transposing is more of a matrix operation than a dataframe op; in any case it's not clear that transposing would help anything, but encoding your data into a less compact but simpler representation (via `gather`) makes it amenable to the ggplot API.

Comment: Oops. Sorry actually I also need Date variable in the first column. I tried to eliminate that. But by doing that we are creating new dataset. I need the same reference dataset that is df

Comment: What I am trying to convey is that, I do not alter df here, I need as it is. Keeping this, is there a way to plot? Hope you got my question:)

Comment: Why can't you copy the data set? If it is super large, then just take a sample of it for plotting purposes. Otherwise there should not be a constraint.

Comment: No No, I got ur point actually. i am using this dataset in R shiny. I have referenced this dataset for 1 operation. At the same I also need box plot for those selected variables. If I change the reference, R shiny wont take dataset as a main dataset. Hope you are aware of R shiny. Hope you got my point:)

Comment: yep, using Shiny doesn't fundamentally change things. If you're stuck, consider clarifying the question or asking a new one with more context. Good luck!

Comment: I found a way, we can do it. Can you guide me. In the same question, can we select any 2 variables that be go in the plot. Like in my question there are 3 Categories right. Can we plot any 2 Categories ?